# Multiple merge of data frame without replacing the values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data frames (df1 and df2), I am planning to merge df1 and df2 based on a columns 'pin', 'pin1', pin2' which are in df1 on column 'pincode2' in df2.

Structure:

```
              df1                             df2

ID Name pin   pin1  pin2  pin3            pincode  value
1  A1   1001  4521  3223  6433            1001     W1
2  A5   1002        4556                  1002     O1
3  X3   4531  4341        4563            1003     X3
4  A4   4633  4633  4633  4633            1004     Z2
5  B3   5346              3452            1005     Y9
6  B4   1001                              1006     G4
7  F5               6512                  1007     R3
```

---

Now I am using the following code to perform merge in pandas:

```
# Importing libraries 

import pandas as pd
import cvs as csv
#********************************************************************#

# Importing the files

df1= pd.read_csv('/Users/one/Input/df1.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df2= pd.read_csv('/Users/one/Input/df2.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

#*************************************************************#   

# Creating a column as a flag

df1['mapping_type']= 'Unmapped'

#*************************************************************# 

# Merging/Joining the two data frame

df_first_run = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on= 'pin', right_on= 'pincode', how='left')
```

As you can see, I need repeat this merge with column 'pin1' 'pin2' of the df1. However I don't want to keep changing the column names df2 or else I will replace the previous got values.

Also the column mapped_type must change to show what column was mapped.

```
Expected Output:

    ID Name pin   pin1  pin2  pin3   value  mapping_type
    1  A1   1001  4521  3223  6433   W1     pin
    2  A5   1002        4556         O2     pin
    3  X3   4531  4341        4563   P3     pin3
    4  A4   4633  4633  4633  4633   Q2     pin2
    5  B3   5346              3452          Unmapped
    6  B4   1001                     W1     pin
    7  F5               6512         Q2     pin2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the map function instead of merging.

Just turn df2 into a hash and map each series separately.

```
mapping = df2.to_dict()['value']
for col in ['pin', 'pin1', 'pin2', 'pin3']:
    df1['{}_value'.format(col)] = df1[col].map(mapping)
```

This will with your example data produce this:

```
   Name   pin  pin1  pin2  pin3 pin_value pin1_value pin2_value pin3_value
ID                                                                        
1    A1  1001  4521  3223  6433        W1        NaN        NaN        NaN
2    A5  1002  4556   NaN   NaN        O1        NaN        NaN        NaN
3    X3  4531  4341  4563   NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
4    A4  4633  4633  4633  4633       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
5    B3  5346  3452   NaN   NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
6    B4  1001   NaN   NaN   NaN        W1        NaN        NaN        NaN
7    F5  6512   NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Which is not exactly what you asked for, but maybe good enough.

If you want to have exactly what you asked for, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
mapping = df2.to_dict()['value']
for col in ['pin', 'pin1', 'pin2', 'pin3']:
    mappedvalues = df1[col].map(mapping)
    hasmapping = pd.notnull(mappedvalues)
    df1.loc[hasmapping, 'value'] = mappedvalues
    df1.loc[hasmapping, 'mapping'] = col
```

Gives

```
   Name   pin  pin1  pin2  pin3  value mapping
ID                                            
1    A1  1001  4521  3223  6433     W1     pin
2    A5  1002  4556   NaN   NaN     O1     pin
3    X3  4531  4341  4563   NaN    NaN        
4    A4  4633  4633  4633  4633    NaN        
5    B3  5346  3452   NaN   NaN    NaN        
6    B4  1001   NaN   NaN   NaN     W1     pin
7    F5  6512   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

However, it should be noted that the last column to change the value will be the column mentioned in 'mapping'. This feels like bad practice and I would probably go with the example above.

Comment: First let me say thank you so much for answering this, I agree with your approach and suggestion of choosing the first one, I only have two doubts, 1. Is it possible to save mapping as a data frame so as to export it. 2. Can I map two columns i.e say 'value' and 'value1'

Comment: @user3875610 you can save dataframes by simply writing `df.to_csv('filename.csv')`. As for mapping two columns, sure, but what do you want to have the columns mapped to? You should update your question.

Comment: Understood, actually i think I am happy with this answer. Thanks for all you help